# Null Pointer Exception in Stackdriver Log Writing

Tags: java, logging, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, stackdriver

I'm using the Java Stackdriver Logging Client library on an OSX.

Before I was developing on a ubuntu with an installed and initialized gcloud sdk. On my Mac, the gcloud is installed but not initialized.

First I'm setting my environment variables:

```
Systemutil.createEnv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT", "projectid");
Systemutil.createEnv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, "path/to/json/serviceaccount.json")
```

Afterwards I want to instantiates my logging client:

```
Logging logging = LoggingOptions.defaultInstance().service();
```

Then I get this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:62)
at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:54)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.rpc(ServiceOptions.java:399)
at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:96)
at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:43)
at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:38)
at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.service(ServiceOptions.java:391)
at LucyLog.StackdriverLogging.write(StackdriverLogging.java:30)
at LucyLog.Lucy.write_Log(Lucy.java:85)
at LucyLog.Lucy.main(Lucy.java:81)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.DefaultLoggingRpc.<init>(DefaultLoggingRpc.java:144)
at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:60)
... 9 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.DefaultLoggingRpc.<init>(DefaultLoggingRpc.java:122)
... 10 more
```

On my Ubuntu, the instantiating is working fine, so what is the init of the gcloud is doing in the background that I have to do in my Java code on my Mac now?

Remark: Setting the cloud_project env is working - if I comment the line, I'll get the other exception. If I comment the line of setting the credentials, the exception doesn't change (maybe the error happens before authentication?)

Answer (score 0):

I also posted my question in the Stackdriver community forum - they gave me a clue that I may have to update my client lib version: [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1595)

I am using version 1.17 now- poml.xml dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now everything works fine.